# Cannot find some Clang command line argument explanations

Tags: clang, clang++

I was going through the Clang documentation and I just found some of the flags seemed to be "undocumented." For example:

- [-fallow-unsupported](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fallow-unsupported)
- [-fassume-sane-operator-new](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fassume-sane-operator-new)
- [-fast](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fast)
- [-fastcp](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fastcp)
- [-fastf](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fastcp)
- [-fautolink](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fautolink)
- [-fbuiltin](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fbuiltin)
- ...

Where can I find their docs/explanations online? Or are their docs hidden (by design)?

Answer (score 0):

After `clang --help-hidden`, your best bet could be to skim through git history.

Checkout https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/ , use a git tool that lets your search the diffs and search for your flag.

By looking at the commit message, surrounding code, and the review process (which goes on at https://reviews.llvm.org ), you can get a good idea of how the flag works.

http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ might be of interest too.